# 3Dplot in maple

Tags: maple

Hello all,

I am considering the function $f(t,u)=e^{(t^{2}+10u-1)}$.

I am also considering the tangent plane $g(t,u)=-121+22t+10u$ at point (11,-12).

I would like to draw a 3Dplot in maple that shows the tangentplane touching the graph of $f(t,u)$ at point (11,-12).

I have typed the following :

plot3d([exp(t^2 + 10*u - 1), -121 + 22*t + 10*u], t = -1 .. 1, u = -0.7 .. 0.7, color = [red, green])

The 3Dplot is not correct. I have spent much time getting it to work. Could someone please assist me?

Thanks.

Comment: The mathematical part is ok. You said that the plot is not correct, how so?

Comment: I can't get Maple to draw the tangentplane correctly. I would like to draw the 3dplot so I can see the tangentplane touching the graph of f(t,u) at (11,-12). I have tried but not succesfully. Can you assist?

Comment: Then you should plot the function in a range that **includes** $(11,-12)$, not in $[-1,1] \times [-.7, .7]$

Comment: I have also done that. The range you see in the question was just a trial. I can not get Maple to give me the output that shows the tangetplane touching the graph as desired.

Comment: Why would you share the code with the wrong range? Anyway, what range did you try?

Comment: Code was just one in may that I tried. In a hurry I just posted the one in question. No big deal.
I tried many different ranges, especially the ones where I capture the point (11,-12).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
plot3d([ exp(t^2 + 10*u - 1), -121 + 22*t + 10*u, [[11,-12,1]] ],
   t = 8 .. 12, u = -15 .. -6, grid=[[151,151],[2,2],[2,2]],
   color = [grey, green, red], style=[patch,patch,point],
   symbol=solidcircle, symbolsize=10, view=-50..50,
   lightmodel=Light2, transparency=[0.1,0.0,0.0]);
```

[image]

Or you could use a narrower pair of ranges for the parameters, eg,

```
t = 10 .. 12, u = -13 .. -11
```

That makes it less obvious that the surfaces are not touching along a line. But if you increase the ranges then you can run into rendering issues (with the chopped `view`, and the large magnitudes).